# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ' '

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to query from a temp table and i keep getting this message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ' '.
```

Can somebody tell me what the problem is?  Is it due to convert?

The query is

```
select compid,2, convert(datetime, '01/01/' + CONVERT(char(4),cal_yr) ,101) ,0,  Update_dt, th1, th2, th3_pc , Update_id, Update_dt,1
from  #tmp_CTF**
```

Comment: Try removing the `convert` field and see if the error still occurs..

Comment: Which database are you using? Some databases use `||` as the string concatenation operator, not `+`.

Comment: Yes , i tried that putting GETDATE() instead of whole convert..still getting the same error

Comment: @Syntactic- its MS SQLSERVR 2008 , let me give it a try ..no it wont work

Comment: @Syntactic, op said SQL Server 2008, but when you see `datetime`, `CONVERT(...,101)` it is TSQL, which could be Sybase or SQL Server, but most likely SQL Server here on SO.

Comment: T-SQL does use `+` for string concatenation, so never mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the OP's command:

```
select compid,2, convert(datetime, '01/01/' + CONVERT(char(4),cal_yr) ,101) ,0,  Update_dt, th1, th2, th3_pc , Update_id, Update_dt,1
from  #tmp_CTF**
```

I get this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '*'.
```

when debugging something like this split the long line up so you'll get a better row number:

```
select compid
,2
, convert(datetime
, '01/01/' 
+ CONVERT(char(4)
,cal_yr) 
,101) 
,0
,  Update_dt
, th1
, th2
, th3_pc 
, Update_id
, Update_dt
,1
from  #tmp_CTF**
```

this now results in:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '*'.
```

which is probably just from the OP not putting the entire command in the question, or use [ ] braces to signify the table name:

```
from [#tmp_CTF**]
```

if that is the table name.

Comment: i did as u told. the error is near ,0 (just after ,101)..
is there something wrong with use of convert?

Comment: this works fine for me: `select 0,2, convert(datetime, '01/01/' + CONVERT(char(4),2010) ,101) ,0,  11, 22, 33, 44 , 55, 66,1`, I had to replace the column names with values because I don't know what your table looks like.  show your entire query.