# Row Delimiter issues with Bulk Insert

Tags: xml, ssms, bulkinsert

Let me give some details and then the issue will a bit clearer, I hope. Data is delimited by the |. Reason for this is that some fields have to keep the commas and making it csv will result in making it overly complex.

Sample data

```
12007|0|10|70|0|2017|1|1|Some County, Nevada|Total Covered|10 Total,all industries
12007|0|10|70|0|2017|2|1|Some County, Nevada|Total Covered|10 Total,all industries
```

Create table script

```
 create table test (
 area_fips varchar(5),
 own_code varchar(1),
 industry_code varchar(6),
 agglvl_code varchar(6),
 size_code varchar(2),
 year varchar(50),
 qtr varchar(50),
 Disclosure_code varchar(50),
 area_title varchar(50),
 own_title varchar(50),
 industry_title varchar(254)
 );
```

Bulk insert command

```
 bulk insert test
 From 'Q:\folder\test1.txt'
 WITH (firstrow=2,FORMATFILE='Q:\folder\xml1.xml',
 ERRORFILE='Q:\folder\error4.txt'
 );
```

XML Format File

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <BCPFORMAT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format">
  -<RECORD>
  <FIELD MAX_LENGTH="5" TERMINATOR="|" xsi:type="CharTerm" ID="1"/>
  <FIELD MAX_LENGTH="1" TERMINATOR="|" xsi:type="CharTerm" ID="2"/>
  <FIELD MAX_LENGTH="6" TERMINATOR="|" xsi:type="CharTerm" ID="3"/>
  <FIELD MAX_LENGTH="6" TERMINATOR="|" xsi:type="CharTerm" ID="4"/>
  <FIELD MAX_LENGTH="2" TERMINATOR="|" xsi:type="CharTerm" ID="5"/>
  <FIELD MAX_LENGTH="50" TERMINATOR="|" xsi:type="CharTerm" ID="6"/>
  <FIELD MAX_LENGTH="50" TERMINATOR="|" xsi:type="CharTerm" ID="7"/>
  <FIELD MAX_LENGTH="50" TERMINATOR="|" xsi:type="CharTerm" ID="8"/>
  <FIELD MAX_LENGTH="50" TERMINATOR="|" xsi:type="CharTerm" ID="9"/>
  <FIELD MAX_LENGTH="50" TERMINATOR="|" xsi:type="CharTerm" ID="10"/>
  <FIELD MAX_LENGTH="200" TERMINATOR="\r\n" xsi:type="CharTerm" ID="11"/>
  </RECORD>
  -<ROW>
  <COLUMN xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NAME="areafips" SOURCE="1"/>
  <COLUMN xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NAME="owncode" SOURCE="2"/>
  <COLUMN xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NAME="indcode" SOURCE="3"/>
  <COLUMN xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NAME="agglvlcode" SOURCE="4"/>
  <COLUMN xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NAME="sizecode" SOURCE="5"/>
  <COLUMN xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NAME="year" SOURCE="6"/>
  <COLUMN xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NAME="qtr" SOURCE="7"/>
  <COLUMN xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NAME="disclosurecode" SOURCE="8"/>
  <COLUMN xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NAME="areatitle" SOURCE="9"/>
  <COLUMN xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NAME="owntitle" SOURCE="10"/>
  <COLUMN xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NAME="industrytitle" SOURCE="11"/>
  </ROW>
  </BCPFORMAT>
```

Error message

```
  Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
  Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
```

Error file

```
  Row 2 File Offset 161 ErrorFile Offset 0 - HRESULT 0x80004005

  12007|0|10|70|0|2017|2||Some County, Nevada|Total

  Covered12007|0|10|70|0|2017|2||Some County, Nevada|Total Covered
```

So it appears that it does not recognize the I between the 10th and 11th fields. It recognizes them before but on this last one, it fails.

1. Is my row terminator of "\r\n" correct?
2. Any other ideas as to why it is not functioning as it should?

Comment: You could mention `|` delimiter when you create the table, so the table will expect data that is delimited by `|`.

Comment: @Ramesh- Sorry. Its been quite the struggle to figure this one out. How does one include the delimiter in the create table script?

Comment: You could do something like: `create table test (
 area_fips varchar(5),
 own_code varchar(1),
 industry_code varchar(6),
 agglvl_code varchar(6),
 size_code varchar(2),
 year varchar(50),
 qtr varchar(50),
 Disclosure_code varchar(50),
 area_title varchar(50),
 own_title varchar(50),
 industry_title varchar(254)
 ) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';`

Comment: You could find a lot of examples online that shows how to create a table using a `|` delimiter.

Comment: @Ramesh, I get the following errorMsg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 57
Incorrect syntax near 'ROW'.

Comment: Instead of putting everything in a single line, put each of the column names on different lines. Look up syntax to creating the table. Follow this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744280/msg-102-level-15-state-1-line-1-incorrect-syntax-near)

Comment: @Ramesh, When I break it up, the same error occurs. I have looked online and the code that you gave seems to be associated with something called HIVE.

Comment: Are you not using Hive to create the table?

Comment: @whatthefish, No, I create it in SQL using a simple create script. Hoping to import the data from flat files on my local machine. The flat file is created by someone else. The bizarre thing about this is that the command works if I narrow it down to the first 9 columns mentioned in the create script.

Comment: Number of columns should not matter when creating the table.

Comment: Are you using mysql database, because varchar is not used in hive?

Comment: @Whatthefish, using SQL Server Management Studio. Have to go for tonight. I can pick this back up tomorrow.

Comment: Oh ok. Even then the number of columns that you want to define, you should be allowed to define them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169778/discussion-between-calflamesfann-and-whatthefish).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not as convoluted as the question was. Anyways, it took 6 weeks but figured it out.

```
  BULK INSERT dbo.test
  FROM 'Q:\folder\test1.txt'
  WITH
  (
  FIELDTERMINATOR = '|'
  );
```

I was under the impression that if it was 123.45, that I had to designate as numeric (5.2) in a format file. Well, apparently not. No format file and leave out the row terminator and it imports fine.